# firebase error W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

- I tried to build app based on login/signup accounts.
- I created it's Firebase and enable the authentication through email.
- I added the google-play-services.json file.
- I added

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
  ```

  in build.gridle(app)

  And in the module I added

  ```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  ```

  And this is my code

  ```
  public class splashscr extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

  TabHost tab ;
  Button logbtn,signup;
  EditText email,password,signupemail,signuppassword;
  private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      tab =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
      logbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
      signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
      password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
      email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
      signupemail =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signupinput_email);
      signuppassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupinput_password);
      firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      logbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
      signup.setOnClickListener(this);
      tab.setup();

      TabHost.TabSpec spec = tab.newTabSpec("tag1");
      spec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginpic));
      spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
      tab.addTab(spec);

      spec = tab.newTabSpec("tag2");
      spec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.signupp));
      spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
      tab.addTab(spec);
  }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     final Intent I = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
      final String emailout = signupemail.getText().toString();
      final String passwordout = signuppassword.getText().toString();
      if (view == signup){
          (firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailout,passwordout)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()){
                      Toast.makeText(splashscr.this, "تم تسجيلك بنجاح ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      startActivity(I);
                      finish();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                      Toast.makeText(splashscr.this, "فشل التسجيل", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  Toast.makeText(splashscr.this,emailout+passwordout, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
      }
  }
  }
  ```

And I get this error:

```
E/ERROR: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED ]
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

what is the wrong?

Comment: Still no solution?

Answer (score 8):

Try re sync your client with your Firebase app, and add again the .json file.
In android studio 2.3 just click on tools>firebase and in the assistant check if your app is connected to.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your emulator has the Play Store.

When you do not have Play Store installed on the emulator, this error occurs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Log into your firebase console and Enable Email/Password Sign-In_Method, it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Firebase console that "anonymous auth" is allowed. It should solve your problem.

Also check INTERNET permission in your manifest. It so obvious, but...

Good Luck.

Comment: the same problem when i added internet permission 
E/ERROR: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED ]

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me after changing the firebase rules. My IOS Simulator worked just fine but Android Emu did not. I fix this by wiping all data from my device in my emulator and then re-launching the EMU. Probably you dont even need to wipe data from emulated device.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you have to tack care of

Internet Permission
,compile library and
Enable only one Auth From firebase auth list not.

In my case i enable 2 Authentication from list Google and Email/Password, so that is not work but after disable Google.. then its work correctly.

I hope my answer is help you.