# Firebase Error: W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is my SignUp Acitivity. I'm trying to create a createUserWithEmailAndPassword with Firebase and add some details to the user's profile such as Full Name, Address and Phone Number. I want to add the user profile under the Unique ID in the "users" database assigned to the new User when creating the user with email and password.

```
public void signUpButtonClicked(View view) {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_text)) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_text, pass_text).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference current_user = mDatabase.child(user_id);
                    current_user.child("Email").setValue(email_text);
                    current_user.child("Full name").setValue(fullName);
                    current_user.child("Nickname").setValue(nick);
                    current_user.child("Address").setValue(fullAdd);
                    current_user.child("Phone Number").setValue(phone);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are now REGISTERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent userProfile = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(userProfile);

                } else {
                    email.setError(null);
                    pass.setError(null);
                }
            }
        });
   }
```

This is how my **build.gradle** looks like.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It doesn't crash but it also doesn't do anything. It just logs this error.

```
12-26 12:12:53.194 4484-4522/com.example.example.example W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
12-26 12:12:56.766 4484-4484/com.example.example.example  W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
12-26 12:12:57.943 4484-4522/com.example.example.example  W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
12-26 12:13:03.621 4484-4522/com.example.example.example W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
12-26 12:13:11.635 4484-4522/com.example.example.example W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Downgrading the Firebase Version or Updating Goole play and Play Services in the phone or Emulator.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
```

or to Firebase version **10.2.6**

Comment: Only this happens:   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: when you downgrode firebase version you have to downgrade google play services verson too.\

Comment: W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms This error is usaully found in latest Firebase Versions. So Downgrading is an one of the Option available to Clear that Problem

Comment: How do I match the Google Play Services Version with Firebase 11.4.2? @Tomin B

Comment: Refer https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417939/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gms-play-services-auth11-4-0/46417988

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580389/firebase-error-w-dynamitemodule-local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-fi

Comment: IT WORKED! The only problem is I still can't proceed since I think Firebase won't accept data into the 'users' child.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161953/discussion-between-tomin-b-and-lloydyu24).

Comment: No problem. I solved the second problem. Your solution worked for "the most part". Now, a new error comes up.
.
.
"Local module descriptor not found"