# W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

---

Firebase not sending the otp on real device. I don't know why earlier it was sending the otp but after i add the dyanamic link in the app then it don't able to send otp.

```
def firebase_version = "16.0.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebase_version"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase_version"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$firebase_version"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"
```

//  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'.

I just uploaded my app on playstore after that I working on next phase of the app. So is this error come because I was working on debug app not on released app?

I have updated the firebase version of different library but nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Error: W/BiChannelGoogleApi: \[FirebaseAuth: \] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973887/firebase-error-w-bichannelgoogleapi-firebaseauth-getgoogleapiformethod-r)